# Deployment plan not getting picked up in weblogic12c

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, web-deployment, weblogic12c

I was trying to override cookie secure feature for a non prod environment using deployment plan. So I generated a sample plan.xml file from weblogic console and updated the same and restarted the server after activating all changes.
When I followed this process on my local machine, my application was working as expected. But on our non production environment, which is hosted on unix box, cookie secure variable does not gets overridden. 
I was doubtful if the Plan.xml is being picked at non prod environment so I intentionally introduced error in plan.xml and then restarted server but application still ran fine. It seems although deployment path is being displayed in console, the plan is not getting picked.
Following are my weblogic.xml and Plan.xml files.
weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
         <wls:context-root>myproject</wls:context-root> 
         <wls:session-descriptor>
             <wls:cookie-secure>true</wls:cookie-secure>
         </wls:session-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Plan.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<deployment-plan xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan/1.0/deployment-plan.xsd">
  <application-name>myproject</application-name>
  <variable-definition>
    <variable>
      <name>SessionDescriptor_Cookie_Secure_false</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </variable>
  </variable-definition>  
  <module-override>
    <module-name>myproject.war</module-name>
    <module-type>war</module-type>
    <module-descriptor external="false">
      <root-element>weblogic-web-app</root-element>
      <uri>WEB-INF/weblogic.xml</uri>
      <variable-assignment>
        <name>SessionDescriptor_Cookie_Secure_false</name>
        <xpath>/weblogic-web-app/session-descriptor/cookie-secure</xpath>
    <operation>replace</operation>
      </variable-assignment>
    </module-descriptor>
  </module-override>
  <config-root>/usr/local/apps/myproject/app_dir/plan</config-root>
</deployment-plan>
```

Is there any separate process to be followed for unix box. Or am I missing something. My process involves following steps
1) Create a deployment plan from weblogic console
2) Update the deployment plan
3) Restart the web application.

Please help, I have been stuck on this issue for one day. Please inform if any other information is required.

Comment: Check with the admin console that the plan is linked to the application. If not, redeploy your application with the plan.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, I checked in console I can see the path of plan.xml in Deployment Plan of the concerned deployment. Is there any other way to check if the plan is being picked.

Comment: You should be able to see an entry in your domain logs something like this: `prefix<somedate> <loglevel> <id> <hostname> <userhostport> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <user>
<> <someuid> <timeepoch> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <versionid> <References were found in the de
ployment plan for module "your.war" with URI, "WEB-INF/weblogic.xml". The plan was merged.>`